# jquery autocomplete, best way to join displayed data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

to keep things simple, I have jquery autocomplete working, what is the best way to approach, joining/displaying a multiple rows from the array in the same input field.

My php looks like this

```
$return_arr = array();

/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($conn)
{
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alltickets where name like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%'");

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['name'];
        $row_array['thedate'] = $row['date'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

My html page looks like

```
>Please enter what you are looking for</p>

<p class="ui-widget">

<label for="event">Please start entering your event </label>

<input type="text" id="event"  name="event" /></p>

<input type="hidden" id="mysqlid" name="mysqlid" />


<p><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" /></p>

</fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

            $("#event").autocomplete({
                source: "autocomp.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#mysqlid').val(ui.item.id);
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

Whats the most effective way to get "date" to be displayed in the text input field named event, right after "name"

so right now If I search, "cam" result will look as so

```
camera
```

I want result to look like

```
camera 17/09/2013
```

I can see there are a few ways to do this, whats the best way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to do it in the `select` event handler. Remember to prevent the default action of the event as well:

```
$("#event").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomp.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.value = ui.item.value + " " + ui.item.thedate;

        $('#mysqlid').val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/33/

---

If you want to display the date inside the list of suggestions, you have a few options:

1. Populate the `value` property with the entire string you want displayed (do the work on the server)
2. Manipuate the response you get from the server to populate the `value` property correctly
3. Override the `_renderItem` function to display the items the way you'd like.

In your case, it seems like #3 is probably the best way to go, so here's how you would do that:

```
$("#event").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomp.php",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.value = ui.item.value + " " + ui.item.thedate;
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + " " + item.thedate + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/34/

Comment: Thank you for youre answer, my function now looks like this   $(function() {

            $("#event").autocomplete({
                source: "autocomp.php", 
    id: '', value: '', thedate: '',
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
     event.preventDefault();
      this.value = ui.item.value + " " + ui.item.thedate;
                    $('#mysqlid').val(ui.item.id);
           $('#checksub').submit();
                }
            });

        });

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my code now looks like this, http://jsfiddle.net/Hhyz5/  the problem is thedate field is not being displayed along with "value", HOWEVER if I push back (on the browser) the date is filled in and everything looks how I want it to?

Comment: Okay maybe I asked my question slightly wrong, the date does fill in, when I select a name from the drop down, BUT how can I make the date appear  next to the results in the dropdown?

Comment: Ah ok, so you want the list of suggested items to include the date? That's doable to, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Mr Whitaker, what direct and precise answers you give, works perfectly, I just wanted to say I really appreciate it, thank you for such valuable input, a great member of stacoverflow

Comment: @user1961525: No problem! Thank you for the compliment :). Please "accept" the answer with the green check mark if it helped.